# python find duplicates in list of dictionaries and merge

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, duplicates

I am using python 2.7
my question is the same as [python list of dictionaries find duplicates based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091000/python-list-of-dictionaries-find-duplicates-based-on-value) 
except I my unique identifier is based on multiple keys (id, name, address,etc.)

And also, based on those keys I have to merge some other values

Any suggestions??

thank you

Answer (score 1):

So with a little help I got to this piece of code

```
uq_map = {}
for rec in outputs:
    #Set values that are marked as unique identifiers
    key = rec["o_date"], rec["o_hour"], rec["co_name"], rec["o_student"], rec["o_class"], rec["o_day"]
    #If they exist we append them to a new defined key 
    if key in uq_map:
        item = uq_map[key]
        print "item ",item
        item['o_teacher_set'].append(rec["o_teacher"])
        item['o_location_set'].append(rec["o_location"])            
    #if not we insert them into new key            
    else:
        item = rec.copy()
        item['o_teacher_set'] = [rec["o_teacher"]]
        item['o_location_set'] = [rec["o_location"]]
        uq_map[key] = item


print uq_map
#This is the loop to remove duplicates from nwe keys
for rec in uq_map.values():
    print 'Teachers: ', '+'.join(set(rec['o_teacher_set']))
```

if there are any more pythonic solutons please let me know

thank you
best regards